# PHP convert a date to a different format

Tags: php, date

Variable `value = 06 августа 2020 23:39` //Month in russian
I need to convert the date format to this: `d-m-Y G:i:s`

This code doesn't work for me:

```
$os = '06 августа 2020 23:39';
$months = array("января" => "01", "февраля" => "02", 
"марта" => "03", "апреля" => "04", "мая" => "05", "июня" => "06", 
"июля" => "07", "августа" => "08", "сентября" => "09",
"октября" => "10", "ноября" => "11", "декабря" => "12");
$os = strtr($os, $months); // echo $os: 06 08 2020 23:39
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d m Y H:i', $os);
$new_date_format = $date->format('d-m-Y G:i:s');
return $new_date_format;
```

Could you suggest a working code?

---

I changed the code and now it outputs the date in the format I need, but the date is output not in one line, but in 3 lines - prntscr.com/u8g8x2 and this leads to an error when saving data. Is there any way to output the result in a single line?

```
$os = $doc->find('.task__meta')->text();
$os = strstr($os,' • ',true);
$os = str_replace(',','',$os);
$months = array("января" => "01", "февраля" => "02", 
"марта" => "03", "апреля" => "04", "мая" => "05", "июня" => "06", 
"июля" => "07", "августа" => "08", "сентября" => "09",
"октября" => "10", "ноября" => "11", "декабря" => "12");
$os = strtr($os, $months);
$os1 = explode(" ", trim($os, " "));
$d = $os1[0];
$m = $os1[1];
$Y = $os1[2];
$os2 = $os1[3];
$G = strstr($os2,':',true);
$i = strstr($os2,':',false);
$i = str_replace(':','',$i);
$s = ':00 +0300';
$date = $Y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d.' '.$G.':'.$i.$s;
return $date;
```

Comment: Does this work for you? `$new_date_format = date_format($date,'d-m-Y G:i:s');`

Comment: The code looks working. Just use `echo` instead `return`. Here working example: https://phpize.online/?phpses=d9c0e853e14f08e026c1e04156f6c82b&sqlses=null

Comment: I use the Parser module: https://github.com/xandeadx/parser ( http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/391 ) for CMS Drupal 7 and when from this page: https://freelance.habr.com/tasks/315310 trying to extract the date http://prntscr.com/u8g0ee by class .task__meta, when checking the code, I get the following text: http://prntscr.com/u8g1h9 perhaps because of the encoding or some hidden special characters or text format, further operations with this date in this module do not lead to results.

Comment: Although in online php code interpreters everything works if you specify a specific date as the variable value in text. Perhaps the numbers from the date need to be converted to digital format or somehow cleared?

Comment: I changed the code and now it outputs the date in the format I need, but the date is output not in one line, but in 3 lines - http://prntscr.com/u8g8x2 and this leads to an error when saving data. is there any way to output the result in a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me when importing data to nodes for the "creation date" field of the material in CMS Drupal 7 when using the Parser module.

```
$os = $doc->find('.task__meta')->text();
$os = strstr($os,' • ',true);
$os = str_replace(',','',$os);
$months = array("января" => "01", "февраля" => "02", 
"марта" => "03", "апреля" => "04", "мая" => "05", "июня" => "06", 
"июля" => "07", "августа" => "08", "сентября" => "09",
"октября" => "10", "ноября" => "11", "декабря" => "12");
$os = strtr($os, $months);
$os1 = explode(" ", trim($os, " "));
$d = $os1[0];
$m = $os1[1];
$Y = $os1[2];
$os2 = $os1[3];
$G = strstr($os2,':',true);
$i = strstr($os2,':',false);
$i = str_replace(':','',$i);
$date = date("d-m-Y G:i:s", mktime(date($G), date($i), 0, date($m), date($d), date($Y)));
return strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PHP function for the return output. In that case, the code would be like,

```
myCustomFormat('06 августа 2020 23:39');

function myCustomFormat($date){
  $months = array("января" => "01", "февраля" => "02", 
  "марта" => "03", "апреля" => "04", "мая" => "05", "июня" => "06", 
  "июля" => "07", "августа" => "08", "сентября" => "09",
  "октября" => "10", "ноября" => "11", "декабря" => "12");
  $os = strtr($date, $months); // echo $os: 06 08 2020 23:39
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d m Y H:i', $os);
  $new_date_format = $date->format('d-m-Y G:i:s');
  return $new_date_format;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when a specific date value is used: myCustomFormat ('06 августа 2020 23:39');, the code works, but if you substitute the variable: myCustomFormat ($os); instead of the text value, the code stops working.
Since my date is dynamic, I need to use a variable. In Your code, what date will you specify in myCustomFormat and this will be the output, so this is where I need to specify the variable?